# Limited instance of php

Tags: php

Is there a way to initiate a limited version of php?

What I want is to create an extremely limited instance of php. Something that could possibly be used publicly to evaluate code without compromising the server. It should support only the basics of a language like variables, looping, printing and thats all. I know ther's a setting that allows to block certain functions but I want to allow only a few language constructs and block 99% of functions.

Comment: PHP safe mode would *probably* do the trick, but is deprecated and really not the right way to handle security.

Comment: Have a look at viper7's codepad: https://github.com/Viper-7/Deployable-PHP-Codepad

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the PHP INI directives [disable_functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) and [disable_classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-classes).

The combination is a good start and commonly used by shared hosts.

I'm not a sysadmin, I'd suggest you reword this portion of your question and put it on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). Nonetheless you could also ensure PHP is on a *sandbox* (by itself, limited external). In addition, an instance that could be easily re-spawned. I'm thinking something like Amazon EC2.

Comment: like I said, I know about these and adding everything that I want to block would create a list bigger then the whole settings file.
Also, I want to block certain language constructs (e.g. include/require) and that cannot be achieved with these directives.

Comment: Understood on `include`/`require`. Those could not be disabled with the above. However, the `allow_fopen` setting would limited them so that they had to be a local file. Then you could trust your system permissions.